# Transparent background of the images are too big

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to position three images with flexbox inside a container, but the images have a transparent background, that somehow interfere with each other.

Here is the html:

```
<div className="buttonContainerLeft">
<img className="images" src={player1Dis}></img>
<img className="images" src={player2Dis}></img>
<img className="images" src={player3Dis}></img>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.buttonContainerLeft {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 25%;
    height: 22%;
    left: 5%;
    top: 38%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    object-fit: contain;
    }
.images {
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Here is the visual example, without the .images class applied, with it works fine:
[image]

What I want is to know if there is a better solution to this problem?

Comment: When you say the transparent backgrounds of the images are interfering with each other, do you just mean that the images are wider than you expected/wanted them to be? You don't seem to have included any styling of the imgs so they will just take their natural widths and the container seems to be too small for them all.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, they are wider.

Comment: Well you may need to use some image editor to get rid of the transparent bits you don't want or you accept them looking a bit small and fit them to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is using a div container for each image then specify the width for this container and use overflow hidden to remove the transparent background.

```
<div className="buttonContainerLeft">
  <div className="image-container">
    <img className="images" src={player1Dis} />
  </div>
  <div className="image-container">
    <img className="images" src={player2Dis} />
  </div>
  <div className="image-container">
    <img className="images" src={player3Dis} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles :

```
.image-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px; //This can be changed depend on how much of the image you want to be shown
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fit all the 3 images into the container, just add to the images `width: 100%`.

Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/krx1gz4h/).

Comment: This will not remove the transparent background from the png images.